# How can i use Alias of CONCAT function(which has updated values) in joined table?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN data.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%xyz 850 G7%' 
            THEN CONCAT(data.DISPLAY_NAME, ' Notebook PC')
            ELSE data.DISPLAY_NAME
    END as u_display_name,
    data.ASSET_TAG AS "u_asset_tag", 
FROM
    VW_ALM_ASSET data
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         ASSET_TAG,
         CASE 
             WHEN data.u_display_name LIKE '%xyz%'
                 THEN SUBSTR(REPLACE(data.u_display_name, '(test) ', ''), 17)
     FROM 
         VW_ALM_ASSET
     WHERE
         data.u_display_name IS NOT NULL) data1 ON data1.ASSET_TAG = data.ASSET_TAG
```

I get an error :

> ORA-00904: "data.u_display_name": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 46 Column: 12

I want to use alias `u_display_name` because it is being updated with `CONCAT`. I want to use its updated value in joined table to create model column but it is showing me "invalid identifier" error.

I tried with both `data.u_display_name` and `u_display_name` identifiers in joined table.

How can I use current updated value of `u_display_name` in joined table?

Comment: Is really all that code needed to show us the problem? Make it easy to assist you - simplify!

Comment: Please post the code that throws an error (and add table definitions to run that query). You may use `with` clause or `select ... from(select ...)` to provide an access to calculated columns as to regular columns.

Comment: done @jarlh, edited in limited format

Comment: FROM is evaluated _before_ SELECT. This means the column alias u_display_name hasn't been created when you try to use if in the subquery. You can use a derived table or cte to fix it. Or simply repeat the case expression.

Comment: thanks @jarlh, i have used CTE and now able to use updated alias values. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-query and `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT data.asset_tag,
       data.u_display_name,
       data1.u_display_name2
FROM   (
         SELECT CASE 
                WHEN DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%xyz 850 G7%' 
                THEN DISPLAY_NAME || ' Notebook PC'
                ELSE DISPLAY_NAME
                END as u_display_name,
                ASSET_TAG
         FROM   VW_ALM_ASSET
       ) data
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT ASSET_TAG,
                CASE 
                WHEN data.u_display_name LIKE '%xyz%'
                THEN SUBSTR(REPLACE(data.u_display_name, '(test) '), 17)
                END AS u_display_name2
         FROM   VW_ALM_ASSET
         WHERE  data.u_display_name IS NOT NULL
         AND    ASSET_TAG = data.ASSET_TAG
       ) data1
       ON 1 = 1
```

However, you probably don't want a `JOIN` as you are joining the table to itself and may instead want a nested sub-query:

```sql
SELECT u_display_name,
       asset_tag,
       CASE 
       WHEN u_display_name LIKE '%xyz%'
       THEN SUBSTR(REPLACE(u_display_name, '(test) '), 17)
       END AS u_display_name2
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE 
         WHEN DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%xyz 850 G7%' 
         THEN DISPLAY_NAME || ' Notebook PC'
         ELSE DISPLAY_NAME
         END as u_display_name,
         ASSET_TAG
  FROM   VW_ALM_ASSET
)
-- WHERE  u_display_name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

See [1.6 Referencing an Aliased Column in the WHERE Clause of SQL Cookbook 2nd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-cookbook-2nd/9781492077435/ch01.html#sqlckbk-CHP-1-SECT-6) :

**Problem**

You have used aliases to provide more meaningful column names for your result set and would like to exclude some of the rows using the WHERE clause. However, your attempt to reference alias names in the WHERE clause fails:

```
select sal as salary, comm as commission
  from emp
 where salary < 5000
```

**Solution**

By wrapping your query as an inline view, you can reference the aliased columns:

```
select *
  from (
select sal as salary, comm as commission
  from emp
       ) x
 where salary < 5000
```

Comment: Hello, here in your example, if i want to use salary, do some modifications with CASE statements and want to create a NewSal column, how does that work. It will ignore salary Alias. That is what happening with me.